# Question Cauchy Riemann equations

Tags: complex-analysis, analytic-functions, cauchy-riemann-equations

Let $f(z) =zRe(z)$.  Determine all points  $z_0$ for which the complex derivative $f'(z_0)$ existst.

I wrote $f(z)$ as $f(z)=f(x+iy)=(x+iy)Re(x+iy)=x^2+(xy)i:=u(x)+v(x,y)i$.

So we get the partials $u_x=2x$, $v_y = x$, $u_y=0$, $v_x=y$.

Now the CR equations, $u_x=v_y$ and $u_y=-v_x$ , only hold in the point $z=0$.

So $f(z)$ is only diffb. in the point $z=0$. So $f'$ exists only in the point $0$;.

Apparantly this reasoning is wrong. But  I don't know what is wrong about it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you have done shows that $f$ is not differentiable at any point other than $0$. The validity of C-R equations at $0$ does not guarantee existence of $f'(0)$. So you have to check existence of $f'(0)$ from definition: $f'(0)=\lim_{z \to 0} \frac {z Re(z) -0} z=\lim_{z \to 0} Re (z)=0$. Hence $f'(0)=0$.

Note: The validity of C-R equation at all points of an open set implies differentiability but validity of C-R equation at a point does not imply differentiability at that point.

Comment: But can't you say that, since $u_x$, $u_y$, $v_x$, $v_y$ are all continuous we have that $f(z)$ is diffb. in $z=0$?

Comment: @paperboy That is correct. But they have raised an objection to your answer because you did not quote that theorem. It is also  better to apply the definition of derivative rather than apply that theorem. It is a mistake to just verify C-R equations at a point and claim immediately that the function is differentiable at that point.

Comment: Okay, thank you Kavi! One more question just to be sure. If my previous comment was added in the argument it would be correct? (Assuming it is ok to use that theorem).

Comment: @paperboy Yes,it would then be correct.